# How to programmatically invoke UITableView swipe left

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to customise the delete indicator for a `UITableView` in editing mode.

[image]

Since I can't seem to find a way to customise the appearance style of the delete button shown in the first image, I've created my own animation with my own button.

[image]

I have deactivated the red standard button using:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {

    return .none

}
```

Now my question: How do I realize the same behaviour as the standard button? If you press the red button, it invokes a swipe left on the cell showing the wanted delete button.

[image]

Help is very appreciated.

Comment: So you want to delete a record on press of your custom delete button, right?

Comment: no. i want the "delete" button that is invoked on a swipe left of a cell, to display.

Comment: but you have mentioned that you have deactivated the red standard button?

Comment: yes. because i want the tableView.isEditing = true, but without the red buttons to appear and use my own custom buttons instead. but i want the same behavior after pressing the buttons as in apple's standard implementation

Comment: So you want to know how to apply action to custom button in UITableViewCell?

Comment: i want to know how to invoke the swipe left of a tableview. or in maybe easier words: when you swipe left on a tableview, the delete button appears (if activated). how do i get this delete button without swiping, but programmatically. this delete button. no other action.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: i was using 3rd party frameworks like IGListKit after all